# Error in button click in listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which contains two textviews, an image and a button I want to do some function on button click with the current listview item. But I i use his code my app close while starting my adapter is

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rowView = convertView;
    ContactStockView sv = null;
    if (rowView == null) {
        // Get a new instance of the row layout view
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.row, null);

        // Hold the view objects in an object,
        // so they don't need to be re-fetched
        sv = new ContactStockView();
        sv.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textrow1);
        sv.number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textrow2);
        //ImageButton buy=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        // Cache the view objects in the tag,
        // so they can be re-accessed later
        rowView.setTag(sv);
        ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText( activity, "abc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        sv = (ContactStockView) rowView.getTag();
    }

    // Transfer the stock data from the data object
    // to the view objects
    ContactStock currentStock = (ContactStock) stocks.get(position);
    sv.name.setText(currentStock.getName());
    sv.number.setText(currentStock.getNumber());
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return rowView;
}
 protected static class ContactStockView {
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView number;
    }
 public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        stocks.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            stocks.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (ContactStock cs : arraylist) {
                if (cs.getName().contains(charText)) {
                    stocks.add(cs);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 private OnClickListener callClickListner=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

call button code

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String phoneCallUri = "tel:" + phonenumber;
                 Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                 phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
                 startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
                //Toast.makeText( activity, "abc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

my adapeter class is

```
public ContactAdapter(Activity activity, List<ContactStock> objects) {
    super(activity, R.layout.row, objects);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.stocks = objects;
}
```

Comment: thanks for all answers +1 for all answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
```

to

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
```

coz you have

```
rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout. You use the view object to initialize view.

Edit:

```
context.startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
```

`startActivity()` is a method of activity class. You need to pass the context to the constructor of adapter class initialize it and then use it like above statement

To pass

```
new CustomAdapter(MainActivtiy.this,..other params);
```

Then

Context context;
   public CustomAdapter(Context contex,..params)
   {
    this.context =context;
   }

Comment: how to perform call this button click. I know how to call on swipe or touch but don't know how to call with a buttom in listview.

Comment: @VikasRana you already have a listener for the imagebutton . what more do you want

Comment: I am posting my code on calling it says startActivity() is undefine

Comment: @VikasRana startActivity is a method of Activity class. You need `context.startActivity(...)`

Comment: this is what i am asking how to make instance contaxt in getView()

Comment: @VikasRana you need to pass the context to the adapter class. You don't know how to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48678/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-vikas-rana)

Answer (score 2):

You should replace this

```
   ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
```

With

```
   ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
```

Becoz your `convertView==null` at this position

Answer (score 2):

Also use `rowView` instead of `convertView` to initialize ImageButton as:

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line.....

```
 ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
```

to this line..

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
```

in getview..